# SQL return bitwise flag value for non null columns indicating data significance

Tags: sql, sql-server, intersect, iif, sqlperformance

I have a case where I need to create a unique weight value based on how much data is contained with a distinct row in a dataset.  Each column is assigned a bit value indicating its significance.  For instance Col1 = 1, Col2 = 2 would signify that Col2 carries more weight than Col1.  Data in both Col1 and Col2 (Col1 | Col2) = 3 would be more significant than a row with data in either column.

Columns at a later time can be reclassified by significance.  Therefore I am looking for a solution which would be more versatile than hard coding the bitwise operation into the SQL query (see Option 1).

I have devised Option 2 as a way to overcome the reclassification requirement but I am not sure if this is the best way to write the query.  My production dataset will range from 4M-25M records.

Can any provide another example, or improve this example, of how to write this query (Option 2) to improve performance and the ability for a user to change the column's significance?

Test Code Below:

Environment: SQL Server 2014

```
--EXAMPLE SETUP
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#DataImage') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #DataImage
    DROP TABLE #Source
END

CREATE TABLE #DataImage (ID INT PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED IDENTITY(1,1), ColumnOne BIT, ColumnTwo BIT, Flag INT)
CREATE TABLE #Source (ID INT PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED IDENTITY(1,1), DataOne NVARCHAR(50), DataTwo INT)
--END SETUP

--CREATE ROW COMBINATION FLAGS (Real Flag Size = 10 combinations)
INSERT INTO #DataImage (ColumnOne, ColumnTwo, Flag) SELECT 1, 0, 1
INSERT INTO #DataImage (ColumnOne, ColumnTwo, Flag) SELECT 0, 1, 2
INSERT INTO #DataImage (ColumnOne, ColumnTwo, Flag) SELECT 1, 1, 3

--CREATE TEST DATA (Real Data Size = 10M records)
INSERT INTO #Source (DataOne, DataTwo) SELECT NULL, 2
INSERT INTO #Source (DataOne, DataTwo) SELECT N'Foo', NULL
INSERT INTO #Source (DataOne, DataTwo) SELECT N'Bar', 100

--QUERY SETUPS--

--OPTION 1:  CALCULATE THE FLAG FOR EVERY ROW
SELECT SourceId = s.ID, Flag = IIF(s.DataOne IS NULL, 0, 1) + IIF(s.DataTwo IS NULL, 0, 2) 
FROM #Source s


--OPTION 2:  RETURN FLAG FOR SOURCE DATA
;WITH t0 (SourceId, Flag, C1, C2) AS (
            SELECT s.ID, i.Flag, IIF(s.DataOne IS NULL, 0, 1), IIF(s.DataTwo IS NULL, 0, 1) 
            FROM #Source s CROSS JOIN #DataImage i
            INTERSECT
            SELECT s.ID, i.Flag, ColumnOne, ColumnTwo 
            FROM #Source s CROSS JOIN #DataImage i
            )
SELECT t0.SourceId, t0.Flag
FROM t0
```

Comment: Maybe I don't understand the question... but... Consider using a computed column to set the flag for each record.  This way the value is set every time a record is changed and the overhead is applied then instead of having to calculate it later.

Comment: Keep in mind that you'll need to mark the computed column as `PERSISTED`, otherwise you won't gain that performance on `SELECT` - it will still need to calculate it each time. Also, this only works if all of the columns are in the same table.

Comment: I like this idea.  I guess I should also mark the column as persisted to ensure it only calculated once.

Comment: I think you definitely understood the question.  This is the route I am going to take.

Comment: The one issue with this approach the more I think about it is that it will 'hard code' the value into  the dataset.  I will need to alter the table each time the column significance changes.

Comment: You will always need to update "something" when significance changes, be the "singnificances" table or be the calculated column. I would go to the calculaded persisted column. Calculating it at flight from the significances table and column values is more complex and less efficient.